# Why doesn't the wrapper wrap around the box?

Tags: html, css

I'm struggling with a problem which seems simple:

**My code**:

```css
* {
    font-family: tahoma;
}
body {
    background: #333;
}
.wrapper {
    padding: 10px;
    background: white;
    width: 100%;
}
.box {
    margin-top: 40px;
    width: 1100px;
    height: 400px;
    background: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box">
        box
    </div>
</div>
```

The box contained in the wrapper has a fixed size, which might overflow the wrapper on small screens. Why doesn't the wrapper wrap around the box? How would I do that?

You can also check out the issue in [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eqhe2o6r/).

Comment: What about min-width:100%; instead of just width: 100% ?

Comment: Should the width of the .box div always be exactly 1100px, or should it shrink on smaller screens?

Comment: @Fuxi check out my answer. It will solve your problem.

Answer (score 4):

In order to make this work:

- Remove `width: 100%` and add to the wrapper `display: inline-block`.
- Doing so, will enable the wrapper to have as much width as needed to wrap around the box. Putting `width: 100%` **restricts your wrapper to the width of the screen** and in case of the box having a bigger with than that of the screen, it won't work.
- If you **do not want to have a horizontal scrollbar**, especially on narrower screens use: `box-sizing: border-box` on the wrapper.

**CSS**:

```
.wrapper {
  display: inline-block; /* Ensures that the box stays wrapped */
  padding: 10px;
  background: white;
  box-sizing: border-box; /* Ensures that there won't be a horizontal scrollbar */
}
```

Here is a [working version](https://jsfiddle.net/eqhe2o6r/7/) of your jsFiddle, with both the wrapping issue mended and the horizontal scrollbar abolished.

```css
* {
  font-family: tahoma;
}

body {
  background: #333;
}

.wrapper {
  box-sizing: border-box display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  background: white;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 40px;
  height: 400px;
  background: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">
    box
  </div>
</div>
```

**For reference**:

- [`display: inline-block;`](https://designshack.net/articles/css/whats-the-deal-with-display-inline-block/)
- [`box-sizing: border-box;`](https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/)

Comment: The OP may want the horizontal scrollbar. @dippas. It wasn't specified otherwise.

Comment: do you really want to scroll in mobile?

Comment: I fixed the horizontal scroll @dippas in spite of having not been asked. Thanks for pointing out :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `display:inline-block` on the wrapper to resize the container based on the content inside.

Answer (score 2):

The `div element` by default has `display:block;` so you need to change its display.

You should remove `width:100%;` from `.wrapper` class, then you can make it `display:inline-block;` or `display:table;`

```css
    *{
        font-family:tahoma;
    }
    body{
        background:#333;
    }
    .wrapper
    {
        padding:10px;
        background:white;
        display:inline-block;
    }
    .box
    {
        margin-top:40px;
        width:1100px;
        height:400px;
        background:#aaa;
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box">
        box
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem occurs, because HTML documents, by default, display all elements as `display: block`.
There are two ways to do it as our friends have mentioned before.

First one is to use `inline-block` value for the `display` property:

```
body{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

The second way is to use `max-width`:

```
div.wrapper{
    max-width: 100%;
    /*we have set height property to auto to have coefficient between width & height*/
    height: auto;
}
```

For more information visit these webpages:

[inline-block](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_inline-block.asp)

[max-width](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_max-width.asp)

Answer (score 2):

**You can solve the problem by using the following css:**

```css
* {
  font-family: tahoma;
}
body {
  background: #333;
}
.wrapper {
  padding: 10px;
  background: white;
  display: inline-block;
}
.box {
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 1100px;
  height: 400px;
  background: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">
    box
  </div>
</div>
```

The only change is I have added `display: inline-block` to `.wrapper` element.

**Why wrapper doesn't wrap around the child div**

The problem is all html element has some default CSS styling which gets applied by the browser.

In this case `div` gets a default property of `display: block;` It is the same property that makes a default unstyled div to take up full available width of it's parent element.

As you can see with this: [snapshot of chrome dev tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SP1m.png)

*The css style highlighted in red rectangle is the default styling applied by the browser.

*The red underlined text tells us about the width of the element. The fading out signifies that value of that property is computed by the browser.

** While we are at it I want to point you to a different problem that you might have faced with the previous code and if the goal was to make the `wrapper` to wrap `box` at all times.

If the `.box` div would have width far less than that of the width of the browser then another problem may arise which I have shown in the code snippet bellow.

```css
     * {
      font-family: tahoma;
    }
    
    body {
      background: #333;
    }
    
    .wrapper {
      padding: 10px;
      background: white;
    }
    
    .box {
      margin-top: 40px;
      width: 100px;
      height: 400px;
      background: #aaa;
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">
    box
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see the `box` tries to cling to a side of `wrapper`.

You can read more about `display` css property here: [CSS display property || CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/)